# a tag in flex messes with the layout of the box

Tags: css, flexbox

Why is the below situation happening? Can't the hyperlink display inline with the rest of the text?

```css
.test {
    padding: 25px;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.2;
    opacity: 0.7;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">No results found. Looks like you may need some expert advice from our Customer Care team! Please <a href="https://ggogle.com">contact us</a> or check your selections.</div>
```

Comment: read this: https://dev.to/afif/never-make-your-text-container-a-flexbox-container-m9p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your text with "p" tag. because it is like bare without it. it can fall apart.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<style>
  .test {
    padding: 25px;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.2;
    opacity: 0.7;
    align-items: center;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="test">
    <p>No results found. Looks like you may need some expert advice from our Customer Care team! Please <a href="https://ggogle.com">contact us</a> or check your selections.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So all that was needed was to wrap the whole text in another container (`p` in this case)? Why was this happening though without a wrapper `p`?

Comment: I think because flex treats any different material inside the flexing div as 'stepbrothers' unless they have a mutual parent which is the p tag

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Nevertheless, your solution solved my problem! So thanks a lot!

Comment: same happens when we use div but I thought paragraph is more suitable for text.

Comment: I'm very happy to be helpful.  Thank you as well!

Comment: Semantically it feels more suitable indeed! :D